# queries with android listview

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, listadapter

I am trying to create a listview that includes a "remove" button on every list item. The item will be removed from the list when it is clicked. Can any one guide me to how can I actually detect the position of the list item if I am using a button onclicklistener? and should the onclicklistener be placed in? (should it be in the list adapter, custom extended listview class or in the activity which holds the listview?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation should be in the ListView's adapter. When you implement the `getView()` method in your list adapter, add the remove feature for the button. The `getView()` method will pass you the position in the array of that item. Here's some what of a [guide](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) to custom ListViews with an ArrayAdapter. Your button's onClickListener should simply call `adatper.remove(item)` to remove the item.